# how can i test if internet explorer version is version 7 or version 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to test if IE is version 7 or 8 and if it is prevent a specific piece of code running?

I've tried the following code but this doesnt seem to work:

```
if($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 8) {
        $(document).on('mouseenter', '.thumb', function () {
          $(this).find('.bgg').stop().animate({ opacity : 1 });
        });

        $(document).on('mouseleave', '.thumb', function () {
          $(this).find('.bg').stop().animate({ opacity : .5 });
        });
      }
```

Ideally I really dont want to use this kind of detection but in this case it has to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to UA sniff for IE in my projects due to the requirement of having only one script file.  We don't want the extra http request that @Kolink's method requires, nor do we want to split functionality. For that I would simply use:

```
var ltie9 = $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9;
```

and then do whatever you want by using:

```
if (ltie9) { ... }
```

I've got a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/Ymyyx/) that shows several different IE detections up to IE10 just to demonstrate.

Comment: The only other thing I have as a global is my object literal namespace that runs my entire script.  I don't abuse it and therefore keep it clean.

Comment: why not including it in your namespace then? Globals are prone to unwanted modification. And UA-sniffing is highly error-prone.

Comment: It works for me in a pretty large environment and I've never had an issue reported suggesting otherwise.  I only UA sniff for IE6 and IE7.  Everything else uses [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com)'s feature detection.

Answer (score 4):

Foolproof method:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript">
    // specific code for IE8 and below goes here.
</script><![endif]-->
```

Comment: +1 for hiding unnecessary from other browsers. (At the cost of a http-request though)

Answer (score 0):

Use [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html). IE7 doesn't provide a `querySelector` method, so for example replace

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) <= 8)
```

with

```
 if (document.all && !document.querySelector)
```

[Here](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/) are some more ideas

Comment: +1 for introducing the general concept of feature detection over doctype sniffing. However, this works only well when trying to detect the feature, you need. Using unrelated features may be error-prone.

Comment: The Nintendo DSi's Opera-based browser doesn't support `querySelector` either. Does that mean that it's IE7?

Comment: @Kolink: I didn't notice the OP using the `Nintendo DS` tag for the question.

Comment: No, but then again they don't have any specific browser tag, suggesting that a solution should work for ALL browsers.

Comment: well, it's a valid objection. If you use a feature for detection that is unrelated to your problem, then you might get some serious problems. FF3 and O9.6 also don't support querySelector.

Comment: @Christoph: that's why I added an extra link and extra check (`document.all`) to the answer. From that page I cite: *However, IE is behind all other browsers so considerably that many features are knowingly unavailable only in IE. Because of that, it is impractical to do formally full-featured, but slow checks in other browsers in such case*.

Comment: looks good, i would put in into a var to only check once though. `var ltie8 = document.all && !document.querySelector;`

Answer (score 0):

IE8 can be used as and act like IE7-

to distinguish, you can test document.documentMode

adding a property to the navigator object saves having to test again

```
//(Run= {};

if(window.addEventListener){
    Run.handler= function(who, typ, fun){
        if(who && who.addEventListener) who.addEventListener(typ, fun, false);
    }// all browsers except IE8 and below
}
else if(window.attachEvent){
    /*@cc_on
    @if(@_jscript_version>5.5){
        navigator.IEmod= document.documentMode?
        document.documentMode:window.XMLHttpRequest? 7:6;
    }
    @end
    @*/
    Run.handler= function(who, typ, fun){
        if(who && who.attachEvent){
            who.detachEvent('on'+typ, fun);
            who.attachEvent('on'+typ, fun);
        }
    }
}
```